# SQL count and compare two created_at columns

Tags: sql, datetime, group-by, count

I have got a table as follows,

| ID | CreatedAt_1 | CreatedAt_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2022-06-10 20:28:37 |  |
| CFR | 2022-06-13 10:00:12 | 2022-06-10 20:28:14 |
| PFR |  | 2022-06-17 12:20:40 |
| XYZ | 2022-06-15 11:00:12 | 2022-06-10 16:45:05 |
| DFL | 2022-06-13 15:00:06 |  |
| FGT | 2022-06-20 10:00:20 | 2022-06-10 13:34:55 |

I already used this query to count number of rows on specific date for each column separately :

```
SELECT
(CAST(datetrunc(‘day’, ‘createdAt_1’ + (INTERVAL '1 day'))) AS timestamp) + (INTERVAL '-1 day')) AS ‘new user’,
count(*) AS ‘count’
FROM Table 
WHERE time_interval
GROUP BY ‘new user’
```

And get something like :

| Day | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-06-10 | 1 |
| 2022-06-13 | 2 |
| 2022-06-15 | 1 |

I would like to be able to compare both columns and get percentage on specific day count(createdAt_1) / count(createdAt_2) * 100 but i don’t see how to easily do it.

Comment: I should have precise that I’m using SQL on Metabase

Comment: _"SQL on Metabase"_ -- "Metabase" is this one?: https://www.metabase.com/product/

Comment: Yes it is this one

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to verify is Metabase SQL supports the SQL standard `coalesce()` function, but the purpose of that function is to return the first non-null value it encounters amongst the parameters passed into it (left to right). If it is supported I suggest the query below.

```
SELECT
      datetrunc('day', coalesce('createdAt_1', 'createdAt_2')) AS "new user"
    , count(*) AS "count"
FROM TABLE
-- WHERE time_interval is true ?? 
GROUP BY
      datetrunc('day', coalesce('createdAt_1', 'createdAt_2'))
```

`coalesce('createdAt_1', 'createdAt_2')` would return the value in `createdAt_1` if that isn't NULL, but would return the value in `createdAt_2` if `createdAt_1` is NULL. If both columns are NULL then overall it returns NULL.

- typically labels are denoted by double quotes e.g. "new user"
- I don't believe you need to add or subtract intervals, or convert to timestamp. The `datetrunc()` function should be sufficient in itself.
- I have not used the "new user" alias in the group by clause as this is my preference
- It isn't clear to me what that where clause is achieving.